# Play Framework 2.2 Null Pointer Exception ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, scala, playframework, nullpointerexception

When I try to save an OPTION to my array list that is contained in my ORDER it throws a null pointer exception.  I am trying to save off each option to the array list in the ORDER class every time the user clicks on it (in the view).  The function gets called correctly with the right option id.  However, every time it tries to save it to the array list I get the null exception.  It allows me to change and save the id and other attributes in the order class though.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Controller Class:**

```
public static Result selectedOption(Long id) {
        System.out.println("Option selected: [" + id + "]     " + "[" + OptionType.find.byId(id).getName() + "]");
        Session session = Http.Context.current().session();
        Orders current = Orders.find.byId(Long.parseLong(session.get("current_id")));
        System.out.println("SESSION ID: " + session.get("current_id"));

        current.optionType.add(OptionType.find.byId(id));
        current.save();

        return ok(pickOptions.render("Options", OptionType.find.where().like("priority", id.toString()).findList()));
    }
```

**Order Class**

```
package models;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity 
public class Orders extends Model {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public boolean is_florida;      // String so form will take leading zero's

    public List<OptionType> optionType;

    public static Finder<Long,Orders> find = new Finder<Long,Orders>(Long.class, Orders.class);  

    public Orders(boolean is_florida) {
        this.is_florida = is_florida;
        this.optionType = new ArrayList<OptionType>();
    }

    public void setIsFlorida(boolean is_florida) {
        this.is_florida = is_florida;
    }

    public boolean getIsFlorida() {
        return is_florida;
    }
}
```

**Routes File**

```
GET     /category/option/:id        controllers.Builder.selectedOption(id:Long)
```

**Script to calls from view**

```
<script>
    $('.select_it, .myState').on('click', function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $(this).toggleClass('myState');

        jsRoutes.controllers.Builder.selectedOption(id).ajax({
            success : function(data) {}
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller Class Where Order is Initialized**

public static Result selectedLocation(String location) {
    Orders current;

```
if(location.equals("ma")) {
    System.out.println("Setting location: [Mid-Atlantic]");
        current = new Orders(false);
} else {
    System.out.println("Setting location: [Florida]");
        current = new Orders(true);
}

current.save();

Session session = Http.Context.current().session();
session.put("current_id", current.id.toString());

System.out.println("Storing id into current session, id: " + session.get("current_id"));
System.out.println("Create a new order in table: [" + current.id + "]   isFlorida: [" + current.is_florida + "]");

return redirect(routes.Builder.pickCate("1"));
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
    2013-10-29 00:05:45,334 - [ERROR] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.NullPointerException

2013-10-29 00:05:45,341 - [ERROR] - from application in play-internal-execution-context-1 


! @6g507nja5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/category/option/1] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:257) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:411) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:408) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [play-iteratees_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:37) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:133) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:254) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at controllers.Builder.selectedOption(Builder.java:38) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(routes_routing.scala:193) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(routes_routing.scala:193) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

**Update**

Tried renaming Option class to OptionType, still getting the same error though.

Example of print out when I comment out the add option type to array.

```
Setting location: [Florida]
Storing id into current session, id: 1000
Create a new order in table: [1000]   isFlorida: [true]
Category selected: [Cold Subs]
Option selected: [1]     [BBQ]
SESSION ID: 1000
Option selected: [2]     [Chipotle]
SESSION ID: 1000
Option selected: [6]     [Mayo]
SESSION ID: 1000
Option selected: [5]     [Marinara]
SESSION ID: 1000
Option selected: [9]     [Sweet Onion]
SESSION ID: 1000
```

Comment: You might want to post the actual stack trace in addition to your code so people can see exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: Your right, updated with the stack trace.  Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, but there is an `Option` class defined in Scala, which might be getting confused with your Option class - what happens if you rename your class?

Comment: Tried renaming Option class to OptionType, and all of the corresponding items.  But I am still getting the same error when I try to add the option type to the array list.

Comment: Also check that `session.get("current_id")` isn't returning `null`.

Comment: Just checked it, it's returning the right order id.  I put the example of the printout above.

Answer (score 5):

In few versions of play mentioned below

- Play 2.1.0 - 2.1.2
- Play 2.0 - 2.0.5
- Play 1.2 - 1.2.5
- Play 1.1 - 1.1.2
- Play 1.0 - 1.0.3.3

when we set a null value to Play session/cookie, we won't get any issues. But mostly rest of the versions throw the below issue.

```
! @6hamjmcc5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/blah/blah] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$$anonfun$4.apply(Http.scala:410) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$$anonfun$4.apply(Http.scala:409) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

This is to avoid a security loopwhole using sessioninjection and null byte session value.

Workaround for this issue is to check for null value before setting it to the session.

May be this will help someone in future.

http://www.playframework.com/security/vulnerability/20130806-SessionInjection